# How to close a popup window?

Tags: dialog-window

I want to give user more information about each function I develop. I want to do that inside a popup window for visual purposes. I do ->

```
PopupWindow[Style["Click here for more info"], 
 Style["bla-bla BLAAAA" , 13, Blue, Editable -> False]]
```

As you can see there is no X to close the window. How can I close this window?

Thank you and happy new year :)

Erdem

EDIT 1

For some reason I don't see the X option on the window but it is there. I think  this is related to my computer since it is working for other users. 
Sorry for taking your time. 
Of course I would appreciate it if someone can tell me what could be the reason not seeing X .

[image]

Comment: works as expected in v9 (windows 10).

Comment: Can you use `Right Click + Close`?

Comment: No I can't do right click and close and  I am using v10 (Mac)

Comment: also same for v11

Comment: I get an X to close the window on mac w/ v11.

Comment: Have you tried the 'weird things are happening` catch-all [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)?

Comment: I just did clean start no help. I have no idea.

Comment: What does: Options[CreateDocument,WindowFrameElements] return?

Comment: Carl it returns {WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "ZoomBox", "MinimizeBox", 
   "ToolbarBox", "DocumentIcon", "ResizeArea"}}  so closebox is there. And I said in my Edit for the question a minute ago. Closebox is there but simply I can't see it. When I click where it suppose to be the window closes.

Comment: You could try using: PopupWindow[..., WindowFrameElements->{"CloseBox", "ZoomBox", "MinimizeBox"}] or some such variation to see how that affects things.

Comment: @Erdem - are you by chance having this trouble after upgrading to Mac OS X Sierra?